# File does not be sent in KDE connect

Tags: networking, lineageos, connection-issues, file-transfer, files

I have galaxy J7 and lineageOS 17.1. When I send a file with KDE connect from my phone to another device (another phone or a laptop) I am successfull, but in reverse not. For example when I try to send a file with KDE connect from my laptop to my phone a notification appears saying "failed receiving file from ...".

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the phone KDE Connect app settings are set for this. Go to the phone's Settings, then to the settings for Apps, select KDE Connect, and then set "Storage Access For This App" to 'Allow'.
2. Ensure that, in the phone KDE Connect app, you click on the device (e.g., a laptop) you're connecting to -- and then set the 'Share and receive' settings *for that device*. Without this device-specific setting, the file transfer attempts may fail.